# Accessing elements pointed to by interator in vector of pointers to structures + pointer type is required

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, iterator

I'm new to C++ and have a little problem accesing elements of my vector. It is a vector of pointers to myStruct in Class A:

```
struct myStruct{
 int val; 
 string name;
}myStruct;

Class A{
 ...
 vector<myStruct*> vec;
 B create()const;
} 

Class B{
 ...
 string Name(); //return name of current struct
 vector<myStruct*>::iterator beginning;
 int offset; //offset from the beginning
}
```

Class A has a method `create()const`, where object of Class B is created. It is supposed to work like some kind of iterator, to go though a part of `vec` with certain properties. The method `Name()` is supposed to return `name` from `myStruct` on possition `vec[offset]`

In `A.create()` I create new object of `Class B`, select the beginning of the iterated part of `vec` by `lower_bound()` and put it in `new_object.beginning`.

When I want to implement `B.Name()`, I can only access the elements of the structs in `vec` by moving the iterator `beginning` and dereferencing it. What is the correct form of a command, that would do what I want - dereference the iterator `beginning` correctly?

The completion in my IDE has lead me to something like `*( *(beginning + offset))->name`, but then it shows an error `Pointer type is required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct form of a command, that would do what I want - dereference the iterator beginning correctly?

type of `beginning` is `vector<myStruct*>::iterator`
type of `beginning + offset` is also `vector<myStruct*>::iterator`
type of `*(beginning + offset)` is `myStruct*`

To access the name member of the `myStruct` element, you need to use `(*(beginning + offset))->name`

You can make it easier to understand the code by using a temporary.

```
myStruct* elementPtr = *(beginning + offset);
elementPtr->name;
```